# Where to keep my log strings?

Tags: python, logging

I have an application where Im logging lots of things, sometimes my log strings get really long so the code gets all messy. Is there any standard way of storing them in another file just to call them by name when needed?

ie. What I have
    LOGGER.error("A really long string, logging all sorts of stuff %s", variable)

Comment: Why would you want to reload your log information into your program?

Comment: the logging module provides this ... you also might want to look at something like logstash

Comment: @Makoto Im not trying to import log information into my program.

Comment: @JoranBeasley How does the logging module provides it?  I have all my logging in place, I just dont want all my code messy with long logging strings all over the place.

Comment: In that case, what do you mean by, "call them by name when needed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course! Store them in a `log_strings.py`(or similar) file and simply import them. Instead of `f.write("This file crashed on _ with error message _") (or whatever) you can just do

```
f.write(log_strings.error1)

#in /log_strings.py
error1 = "This file crashed on _ with error message _"
```

Comment: I would have to import one by one right? Is there any way to import all of them?

Comment: yeah, you know how to use [other files in your project](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), right? Just put all the error strings in the `log_strings.py` file, and when you import them, you import them all

Comment: syntax is just `from <file> import *`